# jQuery mobile function calls before Ajax request end

Tags: android, jquery, cordova, jquery-mobile

Here is my problem. When my Home page shows, I call the LoadUser function, which on success sets the `globalUser` variable with the returned JSON. After it loads I call the alert function but it says `globalUser` is undefined. I have tried many other workarounds, but I always get the undefined message.

If I call the `alert(globalUser);` on the success function, it  works as expected alerting the object.

```
$('#Home').live('pageshow', function(event) {
  $.when(LoadUser()).done(function(a1) {
    alert(globalUser);
  });
});

function LoadUser() {
  $.ajax({
    // connects with the web service and validate de user input
    url: "http://localhost:51396/Icademy.asmx/GetUser",
    contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
    data: { "userName": "'rodrigo'" },
    dataType: "jsonp",
    success: function(json) {
      globalUser = JSON.parse(json.d);
      return globalUser;
    },
    error: function(ret) {
      alert("Um erro ocorreu, tente novamente mais tarde.");
    }
  });
}
```

Comment: Even ignoring the asynchronous nature of the `$.ajax()` call, your `LoadUser()` function doesn't explictly return a value, which means it returns `undefined`. So when you say `globalUser = LoadUser()` then `globalUser` is set to `undefined` too, so you're basically saying `$.when(undefined)...`

Comment: So I have edited the ajax to return the object, and still `undefined`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need to bother you with `$.when` in your case, just implement `$.ajax` in your `pageshow` event

```
$('#Home').live('pageshow', function(event) {
  $.ajax({
    // connects with the web service and validate de user input
    url: "http://localhost:51396/Icademy.asmx/GetUser",
    contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
    data: { "userName": "'rodrigo'" },
    dataType: "jsonp",
    success: function(json) {
      globalUser = JSON.parse(json.d);

      alert(globalUser)
    },
    error: function(ret) {
      alert("Um erro ocorreu, tente novamente mais tarde.");
    }
  });
});
```

Answer (score 1):

I don't see why you don't do everything within the success function. As you say yourself, that works. Plus, you have the benefit of being able to run the code on success. In your example, if there was a problem with the ajax call, yo'd show the "error occurred" alert, but then your when() code would assume success.

With all that being said...

You obviously realize the asynchronous nature of ajax, but you're solving it incorrectly with the .when().done(). LoadUser() returns immediately and it returns null, not a deferred. As such, .done() is probably firing immediately.

The solution is to replace .when(LoadUser()) with .when($.ajax()) as in the example, or return the result of $.ajax (ie, the deferred object) from LoadUser().